# Android clears notification automatically if `alarmId` is present in the notification data

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

I'm building a Cordova app that fires local android push notifications with [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) which appears to be working fine most of the time, but I just ran into this bug where some of my notifications would fire but immediately get cleared from the notification bar. Other notifications would fire just fine. The strange thing is the only real difference between the working and broken notifications is the working notifications have a `data` option that includes a `reminderId` key and the broken notifications include an `alarmId` key instead.

This is broken:

```
scheduleNotification({
  id: notification.id,
  trigger: { at: new Date(notification.timestamp) },
  title: 'Precorrection Alarm',
  text: maybeBlank(alarm.name, 'Unnamed Alarm'),
  data: {
    type: 'alarm',
    alarmId: alarm.id
  }
})
```

But this works fine:

```
scheduleNotification({
  id: notification.id,
  trigger: { at: new Date(notification.timestamp) },
  title: 'Praise Reminder',
  text: maybeBlank(reminder.name, 'Unnamed Reminder'),
  data: {
    type: 'reminder',
    reminderId: reminder.id
  }
})
```

I'm positive the issue is caused by the `data` option because if I remove it from the broken notification, it works fine.

Am I misunderstanding something about how Android is handling this `data` field? I figured it was meant to be used to send app-specific data with the PN, but it appears it doesn't do that at all (the data isn't even available in launch options when opening from a PN).

I'd post this as an issue in the plugin repo, but it's a ghost town in there.